Type errror faced while training Speech Brain Fastspeech2 model
I am getting this error on running : TypeError: AttentionSeq2Seq.forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'grapheme_list'
I am running the fastspeech2 TTS model and trying to train on my custom dataset in a local language from here - https://huggingface.co/speechbrain/tts-fastspeech2-internal-alignment-ljspeech.
The metadata is being accessed fine. But I keep getting this error while the program is trying to access the LJspeech_prepare.py file in the Speechbrain lib.
How do I resolve it ?
